# Regarding glutReshapeFunc()

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have small code drawing a square initially but when I maximize the window it changes to rectangle. I know this has do with aspect ratio and when I add glutReshapeFunc(Reshape); call it works perfectly, I mean after maximizing the window, it remains square only. ReshapFunc is called every time display is modified and before the first display as well. 
I am not getting just by adding reshapefunc, how it maintains aspect ratio. Please help me understanding this. I am copying my code here:

```
void display()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();

}
void Reshape(int w, int h) {

glutPostRedisplay();

}
void init()
{

glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
glutCreateWindow("basics");


glutDisplayFunc(display);
// If I comment this, it will become rectangle.
glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
init();

 glutMainLoop();


}
```

Comment: Is the glutDisplayFunc being called even if the window is not resized?

Comment: @JustinMeiners thanks, i was having incorrect perception of how glutDisplayFunc() works. when i added glViewPort to display() it works correctly. But can you explain behavior of above code, like how it is working in that case

Comment: Im a little confused as well, is display only called on reshape or sontantly

Comment: it is not called on reshape. for reshape i have different function, Reshape()

Comment: glutPostRedisplay causes it to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to the use of `gluOrtho2D (...)`. If you want to preserve aspect ratio, your projection matrix needs to be defined based on the dimensions of your window.

I suggest you do this in your reshape function:

```
GLdouble aspect = (GLdouble)w / (GLdouble)h;

glMatrixMode   (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();

gluOrtho2D     (-1.0 * aspect, 1.0 * aspect, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode   (GL_MODELVIEW);

glViewport     (0, 0, w, h);
```

Comment: If I call reshapeFunc in above program without your changes still it works, can you explain this?

Comment: @Roshan I am not sure what you mean. You should not be calling reshapeFunc yourself, it is a callback that GLUT will call whenever your window is resized.

Comment: @Roshan You need to modify your vertices too when using this orthographic view.

Comment: It worked thanks. Could you please explain how it works? say new size is 500 X 1000. how would it work mathematically.

Comment: @user1737197 It scales the X dimensions of your projection matrix by the ratio of width to height (aspect ratio). This will ensure objects keep their proper shape no matter how you resize the window.